# Mayer-Vietoris for Simplicial Complexes (Reference request)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Is there any book focusing on Mayer-Vietoris theorem specifically for simplicial complexes (i.e. simplicial homology)?

Theoretically there is probably no difference between the simplicial case and other cases (is that correct?), but I would like to see some applications of how does one actually calculate it in the simplicial case.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Alan Hatcher's free AT book?  I can't say for 100% that it's in there, but there's a great chance (and, again, it's free).

Comment: @Randall Yes I have, however Hatcher's book does not focus on simplicial complex at the Mayer-Vietoris section. Thanks.

Comment: The Cambridge third-year algebraic topology course covers Mayer-Vietoris for simplicial homology. Here are some notes typed up by a student in 2015: https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/II_M/algebraic_topology.pdf

Comment: Kozlov's "Combinatorial Algebraic Toplogy".